# If a gas dryer has an igniter, is there any reason for it to have a pilot light?

Tags: dryer

A dryer's gas was recently shut off and turned back on.  The dryer produces heat when turned on.

My experience with gas water heaters and stoves always included a pilot light.   I assumed that this was the case with gas clothes dryers, however, youTube indicates that there is an igniter.

Comment: Seems a waste of gas to use a pilot light when the device is only used once or twice a week.

Comment: Read The Fine Manual. Manufacturer implementations will vary, as will the same manufacturer's products over time. This can't be usefully generalized; however standing pilots are definitely less common in current products, due to the waste of gas and the impact on efficiency numbers. The gas range I grew up with had pilot lights and the gas range I currently have uses spark ignition for the top and a glow-igniter for the oven. Other than the fact that this makes the oven useless in a power outage, and how overpriced oven igniter replacements are,  it's generally better.

Comment: There are many kinds of igniters.   I think most dryers use a glow bar 
 but this isn't an appliance design forum.  You can ask a specific question about yours.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I have to replace my oven glow bars constantly like printer ink.  Do you have that problem?

Comment: So far I've gotten away with only having to do it once, but the offensiveness of the pricing stuck with me (and it's likely even higher now.)

Answer (score 0):

Pilot lights are pretty much obsolete.  They use gas all the time, even when the appliance is off.  When added up over a year, even a small pilot light will use a lot of gas.

These days, automatic ignition by an electronically generated spark, or by a hot wire, is more efficient.

Comment: But as to how _your_ unit is set up: check the manual. If gas, don't guess; the consequences of getting it wrong can be explosive.